# Big difference in throughput when using MSMQ as subscription storage for Nservicebus as opposed to RavenDB

Tags: performance, nservicebus, publish-subscribe

Recently we noticed that our Nservicebus subscribers were not able to handle the increasing load. We have a fairly constant input stream of events (measurement data from embedded devices), so it is very important that the throughput follows the input.

After some profiling, we concluded that it was not the handling of the events that was taking a lot of time, but rather the NServiceBus process of retrieving and publishing events. To try to get a better idea of what goes on, I recreated the Pub/Sub sample (http://particular.net/articles/nservicebus-step-by-step-publish-subscribe-communication-code-first).

On my laptop, using all the NServiceBus defaults, the maximum throughput of the Ordering.Server is about 10 events/second. The only thing it does is

```
class PlaceOrderHandler : IHandleMessages<PlaceOrder>
{
    public IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Handle(PlaceOrder message)
    {
        Bus.Publish<OrderPlaced>
            (e => { e.Id = message.Id; e.Product = message.Product; });
    }
}
```

I then started to play around with configuration settings. None seem to have any impact on this (very low) performance:

```
Configure.With()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .UseTransport<Msmq>()
           .MsmqSubscriptionStorage();
```

With this configuration, the throughput instantly went up to 60 messages/sec.

I have two questions:

1. When using MSMQ as subscription storage, the performance is much better than RavenDB. Why does something as trivial as the storage for subscription data have such an impact?
2. I would have expected a much higher performance. Are there any other configuration settings that I should use to get at least one order of magnitude better than this? On our servers, the maximum throughput when running this sample is about 200 msg/s. This is far from spectacular for a system that doesn't even do anything useful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSMQ doesn't have native pub/sub capabilities so NServiceBus adds support this by storing the list of subscribers and then looping over that list sending a copy of the event to each of the subscribers. This translates to X message queuing operations where X is the number of subscribers. This explains why RabbitMQ is faster since it has native pub/sub so you would only need one operation against the broker.

The reason the storage based on a msmq queue is faster is that it's a local storage (can't be used if you need to scaleout the endpoint) and that means that we can cache the data since that can't be any other endpoint instances updating the storage. In short this means that we get away with a in memory lookup which as you can see is the fastest option.

There are plans to add native caching across all storages:

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1320

200 msg/s sounds quite low, what number do you get if you skip the bus.Publish? (just to get a base line)

Comment: When I skip the bus.Publish, I get closer to 250 msg/s.

Comment: 250 is very low (I get around 2200 msg/s) doing empty receives on my box. How many threads are you using?

Comment: The number of threads ( MaximumConcurrencyLevel ) don't seem to change much. When set to 1 it's a bit slower, when set to 100 it's a little bit faster, but no major improvements.
Since your answer covers the first question, I'm going to flag this as the accepted answer, and fork off the discussion on performance to another post: I'll add all the relevant info there, so it should be clearer.

Comment: I am nearing 1600 msg/s on msmq doing empty receives. Using 50 threads and no throughput limit. Will try one of our staging environments one of these days. That should be even better.

Comment: According to our tests 5-8 threads seems to give the best throughput for empty receives?(50 sounds very high)

Answer (score 0):

**Possibility 1: distributed transactions**
Distributed transactions are created when processing messages because of the combination Queue-Database.
Try measuring without transactional handling of the messages. How does that compare?

**Possibility 2: msmq might not be the best queueing system for your needs**
Ever considered switching to rabbitmq for transport? I have very good experiences with RabbitMq in combination with MassTransit. Way exceed the numbers you are mentioning in your question.

Comment: Actually, I had already disabled transactions, using             Configure.Transactions.Disable();

Comment: Any chance you can package your sample application. I can run this on our infrastructure and also swap msmq with rabbitmq.

Comment: Just tried RabbitMQ, it's about 20 times faster. Still doesn't answer the questions though.

Comment: Can't really answer Q1. I have switched entirely to RabbitMq after evaluating NServiceBus and MassTransit. In combination with MassTransit, RabbitMq is the more obvious choice and I haven't regretted this one moment.  As for Q2, by changing your configuration to use RabbitMq you got a magnitude of x20. Not bad I'd say. What are you targetting?

Comment: Can't really tell what I'm aiming for, as this is not a real life situation: the handler in this sample doesn't really do much. It's just a sample to figure out why we can't get a higher throughput.
It looks like we will need to reconsider the use of MSMQ for our NserviceBus setup. But that means going through another learning curve on how to set up and especially manage it using RabbitMQ (or another transport provider).

Comment: The details of the implementation are of course up to you and your project team to decide. On setting up RabbitMQ on Windows I wrote this small blogpost: http://blog.leanhangout.be/?tag=/RabbitMQ. I plan to write more and more on how we use it and more specifically how we use MassTransit.